# Subsuperscript in a different way

Tags: output-formatting

I am using the following format for subsuperscript:

```
Format[subsup[body_, sub_, sup_]] := Subsuperscript[body, sub, sup]
Format[SX[a_, b_, c_, d_]] := Subsuperscript[SX , {c, d}, {a, b}]
```

Is there a way to create the same without any curly brackets and commas. I meant I need $$SX_{cd}^{ab}$$. Can I generate exactly as above.

Comment: `Subsuperscript[SX, Row@{c, d}, Row@{a, b}]` or `Subsuperscript[SX, StringRiffle[{c, d}, ""], StringRiffle[{a, b}, ""]]`?

Comment: @kglr But Mathematica is crashing with these things. Can you please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253508/copying-to-latex-issue-crashing-mathematica